# How to create a horizontally striped table

Tags: html, css

It is easy to create a vertically striped table, but what about a horizontally one? consider the following code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>Q</td>
    <td>R</td>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>T</td>
    <td>U</td>
    <td>V</td>
    <td>W</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>Z</td>
  </tr>
    <tr> <td>Z</td> <td>Y</td> <td>X</td> <td>W</td> <td>V</td> <td>U</td> <td>T</td> <td>S</td> <td>R</td> <td>Q</td> <td>P</td> <td>O</td> <td>N</td> <td>M</td> <td>L</td> <td>K</td> <td>J</td> <td>I</td> <td>H</td> <td>G</td> <td>F</td> <td>E</td> <td>D</td> <td>C</td> <td>B</td> <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What css setting can help achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `:nth-child` selector, but on `<td>` elements instead of `<tr>`:

```css
tr td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: yellow;
}
tr td:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>I</td>
        <td>J</td>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>N</td>
        <td>O</td>
        <td>P</td>
        <td>Q</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>T</td>
        <td>U</td>
        <td>V</td>
        <td>W</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Z</td>
    </tr>
        <tr> <td>Z</td> <td>Y</td> <td>X</td> <td>W</td> <td>V</td> <td>U</td> <td>T</td> <td>S</td> <td>R</td> <td>Q</td> <td>P</td> <td>O</td> <td>N</td> <td>M</td> <td>L</td> <td>K</td> <td>J</td> <td>I</td> <td>H</td> <td>G</td> <td>F</td> <td>E</td> <td>D</td> <td>C</td> <td>B</td> <td>A</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're fast like an eagle @TheEagle )))

Comment: do you know how to get rid of that empty space that separated the two letters.

Comment: @Learning add `border-collapse: collapse;` to the table

Comment: Thanks @juan, you were like reading my thoughts)